# How to get day or year number from timestamp column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Timestamp column in a table like this on postgres

```
CreatedAt

2016-10-26 07:33:51.029
2016-11-01 08:39:12.322
```

I need to get day like

```
SELECT day number or may be month number 
FROM "MyTable";
```

expected output would be

```
day

26
01
```

Comment: `date_part('day', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT to_char("your column",'DD') as "day" 
FROM "MyTable";
```

more at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 6):

Use the `extract()` function:

```
select extract(day from createdat) as day,
       extract(year from createdat) as year
from "MyTable";
```

More details in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT